# method to add custom cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, customization

i want to add a method to my customCell.m which allows me to add informations about the cell in one line so i added:

```
 -(void) addInfo:(NSString*) pTitre:(NSString*) pDescritption:(NSString*) pDate: (NSString*)pImage
{
    [[self titre] setText:pTitre];
    [[self description] setText:pDescritption];
    [[self date] setText:pDate];
    [[self couverture] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:pImage]];
}
```

but when i call the method in mytableview.m as follow:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 3 ;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"firstviewcustomcellCell";

firstviewcustomcellCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *topLevelObject=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"firestViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];

            for(id currentObject in topLevelObject)
            {
                if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[firstviewcustomcellCell class]])
                {
                    cell=(firstviewcustomcellCell*) currentObject;
                    break;
                }
            }    
}
    [cell addInfo:
     @"journal 1":
     @"description 1":
     @"01/02/2012":
        @"second.png"];

    [cell addInfo:
     @"journal 2":
     @"description 2":
     @"01/02/2012":
     @"second.png"];

    return cell;

}
```

This is what it shows:

http://img213.imageshack.us/img213/2346/capturedcran20120416142.png

Thank you for your time

Comment: Isn't the second call to `addInfo` overwriting the first call?

Comment: isn't supposed to be a different cell?

Comment: as @Nit has already pointed out, you need some sort of *logic* to determine what to populate the cell with - you are always doing the same thing for all cells, hence the result you are seeing.

Comment: @Hosni Go to the Apple developer site and read their documentation about Model View Controllers and look at the example code for UITableView. If you continue along the way you are doing, even if you get this working (using the answers below) then you are going to make things MUCH more difficult for yourself in the future. The current set of answers only show how to get what you currently have working. They don't show the correct way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

```
[cell addInfo:
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"journal 1"]:
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"description 1"]:
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"01/02/2012"]:
    @"second.png"];

[cell addInfo:
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"journal 2"]:
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"description 2"]:
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"01/02/2012"]:
 @"second.png"];
```

Please observe this part of your code.. 
There is no condition there.

Instead do it like this

```
[cell addInfo:
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"journal %i", indexpath.row]:
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"description %i", indexpath.row]:
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"01/02/2012"]:
    @"second.png"];
```

Comment: this is actually works for this situation only  but not when i use:[cell addInfo:
         @"journal 1":
         @"description 1":
         @"01/02/2012":
            @"second.png"];
    
        [cell addInfo:
         @"journal 2":
         @"description 2":
         @"01/02/2012":
         @"second.png"];

Comment: U will get repeated data, since second call overwrites first one

Comment: @Hosni the other option is to add data in dictionary and add it in array so after that you have to give objectAtIndex valueForkey . so it will display data as per array index.

Comment: @Chinttu can you post a detailed answer about that please

Answer (score 0):

You can not add all the cells information at once...you have to add one cell info at once...and if you want to add all the cells info add at once than put condition...like..

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return 3 ;
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"firstviewcustomcellCell";

   firstviewcustomcellCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil)
 {    
  NSArray *topLevelObject=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"firestViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for(id currentObject in topLevelObject)
        {
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[firstviewcustomcellCell class]])
            {
                cell=(firstviewcustomcellCell*) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }    
   }



if(indexPath.row == 1)
 {
  [cell addInfo:
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"journal 1"]:
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"description 1"]:
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"01/02/2012"]:
    @"second.png"];
}
  else if(indexPath.row == 2)
 {

  [cell addInfo:
  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"journal 2"]:
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"description 2"]:
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"01/02/2012"]:
 @"second.png"];
 }

return cell;

 }
```

Hope, It will help you...Chill